# LINQ query on child list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'd like to write a linq query which checks an object against a list of objects inside another object.

Here is what I've come up with, which doesn't yield the correct results, because it only defaults to the first one, so objects at both `Site 1` and `Site 2` only show at `Site 1`:

```
filteredData = data
               .where(f => filterInfo.Site.Name.Contains
                               (f.EtaSites.FirstOrDefault().Site.Name)).ToList()
```

So, `data` is a list, and within each `Data` object, there is a list of `EtaSites`.  Each `EtaSite` has a `Site`.  A `Data` object could be in more than one `Site`, i.e., there are two `EtaSites` objects in the list.  My query should pull any `Data` object that has the selected `Site` in the list.  So, for ones at more than one site, we should be able to select `Site 1` or `Site 2` and return the same `Data` object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
filteredData = data
    .Where(f => f.EtaSites
        .Any(a => filterInfo.Site.Name.Contains(a.Site.Name)))
    .ToList();
```

Anyway, the example above lets you select only the *exact* matches in your filter. I believe you should consider the one below, if you want that to use a partial matching value in the `filterInfo.Site.Name`:

```
filteredData = data
    .Where(f => f.EtaSites
        .Any(a => a.Site.Name.Contains(filterInfo.Site.Name)))
    .ToList();
```